# Subset data frame to get rowname, colname and value

Tags: r

I have a data frame like

```
Phe  Ile  
Leu  0.10 0.27 
Ile  0.67 0.00 
Val  0.66 0.87 
B.Hy 0.09 0.41
```

I want to subset data for values greater than 0.5, so the expected result is

```
Phe Ile 0.67
Phe Val 0.66
Ile Val 0.87
```

I wrote a function as

```
extract <- function(x){if(x[i,j] > 0.5){print x[1,j]"\t"x[j,1]"\t"x[i,j] }}
```

but it gave error as

> unexpected symbol in "extract <- function(x){if(x[i,j] > 0.5){print x"

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `melt` the dataset to reshape from 'wide' format to 'long' format after converting the 'data.frame' to 'matrix'.  This will result in a 'rowname', 'columname' and value' column, from which we can `subset`, the rows with the logical condition `value > 0.5`.

```
 library(reshape2)
 subset(melt(as.matrix(df1)), value>0.5)[,c(2:1,3)]
 #  Var2 Var1 value
 #2  Phe  Ile  0.67
 #3  Phe  Val  0.66
 #7  Ile  Val  0.87
```

NOTE: In the expected output, the column names column is first, followed by row names and then the value column.  Usually, it is in the order `rowname/colname/value`

---

A `base R` option would be to create a logical matrix (`df1> 0.5`).  This can be used to subset the rownames.  We can multiply the 'indx' with `row`  or 'col` of 'df1' to get the numeric row/column positions that correspond to 'TRUE' values in the 'indx' while the 'FALSE' will be replaced by '0'.  Based on the numeric index, we filter the rownames and column names.

```
 indx <- df1>0.5
 rn <- rownames(df1)[row(df1)*indx]
 cn <-  colnames(df1)[col(df1)*indx]
 val <- df1[indx]
 data.frame(rn, cn, val)
 #   rn  cn  val
 #1 Ile Phe 0.67
 #2 Val Phe 0.66
 #3 Val Ile 0.87
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Phe = c(0.1, 0.67, 0.66, 0.09), 
 Ile = c(0.27, 
 0, 0.87, 0.41)), .Names = c("Phe", "Ile"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("Leu", "Ile", "Val", "B.Hy"))
```

Comment: [1] Var2  Var1  value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(value, 0.5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors  so it can't subset the factors

Comment: @Haroon Looks like in your dataset, the columns are not numeric, but 'factors'.  In that case, convert to numeric.  i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`  Have you tried with the data in my post.

Comment: yes data in your post does works. First column is a factor which is the default rownames.

Comment: @Haroon  I assumed you have two columns `Phe` and `Ile` which are 'numeric' and the rownames is just rowname.  Have you tried after converting the class of your dataset?

Comment: @Haroon If you have 3 columns with the first being rowname and again assuming that the 2nd and 3rd are numeric, just do `df2 <- df1[-1]; row.names(df2) <- df1[,1]` and then do the steps as in the code replacing `df1` with `df2`

Comment: Thanks a ton it worked. May I know why it didn't recognised the first col as row names when I imported the data as read.table ?