# How to find the max value in a list and its row and column index in R?

Tags: r

I have a list like this:

```
> A
 [[1]]
            Jan Feb Mar
Product_A   14   7  90 
Product_B    1   2   3

 [[2]]
            Jan Feb Mar
Product_C   15   7   9
```

I want to have the max value in this list and its row and column names. I would like to see something like this:  90, Product_A, Mar 
I really appreciate it if somebody could help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Behnaz, I rolled back your edit intending to show an image of your data, primarily because it is much more useful to have something we can use. An image of code or data are discouraged: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Further, I put your sample data in a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), it helps with presentation and interpretability of your question to format it properly.

Comment: Since this is a `list`, I suggest you figure out how to do it to one matrix (`A[[1]]`), and then repeat it on each element of the list with `lapply(A, ...)` where `...` is what you do with a single matrix. (Or, you can just combine all matrices in the list into a single matrix with `do.call(rbind, A)` and use your one-matrix-solution on that one matrix ... assuming the data structure allows, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

To me it is unclear whether you want to names of the max value of the whole list or of every dataframe inside the list. There is already an answer from @RonakShah for the latter interpretation, so I post one if you look for names of one max value of the whole list. Using `list.which` and the idea of a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024620/subset-data-frame-to-get-rowname-colname-and-value) you can do

```
library(rlist)
library(reshape2)

max_val <- max(unlist(list_df))
which_list <- list.which(list_df, max(Jan, Feb, Mar) == max_val)
df <- list_df[[which_list]]

subset(melt(as.matrix(df)), value == max_val)
Var1       Var2   value
Product_A  Mar    90
```

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans mentioned, we can try to find out how to solve it for one matrix/dataframe and then use `lapply` to apply it to list of dataframes. Assuming your list is called `list_df` one way would be

```
get_max_row_col <- function(x) {
   val <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   arr <- which(x == val, arr.ind = TRUE)
   data.frame(value = val, rowname = rownames(x)[arr[, 1]], 
              column_name = colnames(x)[arr[, 2]])
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(list_df, get_max_row_col))

#  value   rowname column_name
#1    90 Product_A         Mar
#2    15 Product_C         Jan
```

We can also use `purrr`'s `map_df` or `map_dfr` with the same function

```
purrr::map_df(list_df, get_max_row_col)
```

---

As @schwantke points out that if you want to find one maximum value in the entire dataframe you can skip the `lapply` part bind all the dataframe together in one list and perform the calculation.

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind, list_df)
val <- max(df1)
arr <- which(df1 == val, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(value = val, rowname = rownames(df1)[arr[, 1]], 
           column_name = colnames(df1)[arr[, 2]])

#  value   rowname column_name
#1    90 Product_A         Mar
```

**data**

```
list_df <- list(structure(list(Jan = c(14L, 1L), Feb = c(7L, 2L), Mar = c(90L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Product_A", "Product_B"
)), structure(list(Jan = 15L, Feb = 7L, Mar = 9L), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = "Product_C"))
```

Comment: I like the post but it doesn't run for me. I think there is a typo: x and not df1..

Comment: @schwantke yes, I think I missed to change it after testing it on 1 dataframe. Thanks for informing, I have corrected it :)